# Unable to PSEXEC into machine with admin hash

Tags: windows, penetration-test, metasploit

I'm doing a penetration test at the moment, and I am trying to PSEXEC into a machine for which I have the local administrator hash.

I am attempting this with metasploit and metasploits psexec module.

I have LHOST set to my local IP, rhost set to the target IP, SMBUser is set to 'Administrator' and SMBPass is set with the hash.

However, I get an access denied error, which..surely should not be the case? Target is a Windows 7 machine.

I do this regularly as part of penetration tests and have not run into this error before, wondering what the cause could be?

Comment: Is the SMBDomain settings correct? Are you able to run auxiliary/scanner/smb/smb_version on this machine?

Comment: Ensure that the hash you have is really for the RID 500 account. It could be possible that IT renamed a different account to Administrator. If you have the hash of a user in the local admin group (but this user is not RID 500) you may be running into UAC remote restrictions with Windows Vista and newer (see https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/951016 ).

Comment: Just in case - french versions of Windows name their administrative account **Administrateur**.

Answer (score 2):

This could be two things.

If your account is in fact RID 500 then the registry key `FilterAdministratorToken` might be set to prevent SMB logins to built-in administrator having admin privileges.

If the account is not RID 500, then UAC or the `LocalAccountTokenFilterPolicy` registry key is filtering the token with the elevated privileges (so your account acts as a normal user without access to the service required for PSExec).

See http://www.harmj0y.net/blog/redteaming/pass-the-hash-is-dead-long-live-localaccounttokenfilterpolicy/ for more info.

Answer (score 1):

What type of payload are you using, powershell, Python, etc? and what type of connection is being made, reverse shell or bind shell? Often times I run into errors when I use a reverse shell payload from an NAT virtual machine.

For what you are describing the powershell payload sounds best:
Set payload Windows/meterpreter/bind_tcp

If the correct ports are open, the right network settings are used, the right payload is set, and the right creds are used you shouldn't have a problem.

Happy Hacking!